# Customized Shipping section on cart and checkout page not showing in woocommerce email template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have here a code that adds the "**Total shipping cost**" based on the shipping rate per product

```
function action_woocommerce_after_shipping_rate( $method, $index ) { 
    global $woocommerce;

    $sub_ed_total = preg_replace('/&.*?;/', '', WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal());
    $ed_total = preg_replace('/&.*?;/', '', WC()->cart->get_cart_total());
    $str = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $sub_ed_total);
    $str2 = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $ed_total);

    $ed_tototal = $str - $str2;

    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Total shipping: '.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().number_format((float)abs($ed_tototal), 2, '.', '');
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
}; 

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', 'action_woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', 10, 2 );
```

**Its working on my checkout page and cart page**
[image: checkout page]

**and here is the email template after purchase**

[image]

You see that in the email template the "Total shipping: £17.00" is not showing and I don't know how to make it show up in the email template

Please help as I am having a headache now trying to solve this problem, thanks

Comment: Have you tried by printing that value inside the function ?

Comment: I mean inside action_woocommerce_after_shipping_rate function

Comment: You can Override woocomerce Email Templates that is in plugin direcrory woocommerce\templates\emails\email-order-items.php copy this file and add in your theme directory with same folder structure.

Comment: Hi @TejasMehta how do i do that? printing value inside the function

Comment: I think @khushi is right, try by replacing the file.

Comment: @TejasMehta I have tried doing the email templates but a fatal error occured when I place this WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal() in the template

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'wdm_add_shipping_method_to_order_email', 10, 2 );
function wdm_add_shipping_method_to_order_email( $order, $is_admin_email ) {
    echo '<p><h4>Shipping:</h4> ' . $order->get_shipping_method() . '</p>';
}
```

Using this you can override default text of shipping. May this help. 
You have to just replace $order->get_shipping_method() to your code.

Comment: I have tried that already but it displays under the table, which it should be inside the shipping row

Comment: Okay then let me check another hook for that